# Buttons are not showing on tablerow

Tags: android, button, tablerow

I decided to create my layout dynamically, because I feel more in control of them as I can do anything with in code rather than having the layout, inflate, etc, etc. I come from developing first with Symbian, then Blackberry and even though having an drag-and-drop layout creation interface is rather cool, I feel more at home with this. Though I'll still use some D&D layouts.

The thing is, I have this layout with the spinner and some buttons, and I want them to be in a row style, so obviously I set them in a table row. Here's the code:

```
public FormaLibrosDisponibles(SisLec _sisLec)
    {
        super(_sisLec);
        sisLec = _sisLec;
        disenio = new LinearLayout(sisLec);
        disenio.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        addView(disenio);
        selecClk = new OnClickListener() 
        {           
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {           
                seleccionarBtnClick(v);
            }
        };
        cancelarClk = new OnClickListener()
        {           
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                cancelarBtnClick(v);
            }
        };      
        selecBtn = new Button(sisLec);
        selecBtn.setText("Descargar Libro");
        selecBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        selecBtn.setOnClickListener(selecClk);
        cancelarBtn = new Button(sisLec);
        cancelarBtn.setText("Cancelar");
        cancelarBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        cancelarBtn.setOnClickListener(cancelarClk);
        lineaTabla = new TableRow(sisLec);
        lineaTabla.addView(selecBtn);
        lineaTabla.addView(cancelarBtn);
        lineaTabla.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        librosDisponibles = new Spinner(sisLec);
        disponiblestxtVw = new TextView(sisLec);
        disponiblestxtVw.setText("Libros Disponibles");
        disenio.addView(disponiblestxtVw);
        disenio.addView(librosDisponibles);
        disenio.addView(lineaTabla);
    }
```

But when it fires up, there are no buttons shown. And if I take out the layout params of either button, lets say I do this:

```
selecBtn = new Button(sisLec);
            selecBtn.setText("Descargar Libro");
            //selecBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            selecBtn.setOnClickListener(selecClk);
            cancelarBtn = new Button(sisLec);
            cancelarBtn.setText("Cancelar");
            cancelarBtn.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            cancelarBtn.setOnClickListener(cancelarClk);
```

... then only cancelarBtn will be shown, and will take all the space.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your TableRow to a TableLayout, instead of adding it to a LinearLayout.

```
disenio = new TableLayout(sisLec);
```

Comment: thing is, i checked out the other layout i have, with a tablerow in it, and it is a simple linearlayout, but yeah, i'll try your suggestion

Comment: Didn't worked. Changed from linear to table and still, buttons wont appear